# Meaning of 早口 - fast talker

Tags: meaning

WaniKani and Jisho.org give the definition of 早口{はやくち} as "fast talker".  In English, this can have several shades of meaning.  Which of the following (or others) apply in Japanese:

- someone who speaks rapidly:  *she's such a fast talker I can't understand a word she says*
- a salesman or con-artist;  they talk so fast you can't keep up and you end up agreeing to something you're not quite sure of:  *A fast talking salesman who could sell a freezer to an Eskimo*
- someone who can get out of tricky situations.  *He's such a fast talker he always gets in trouble but rarely suffers the consequences.*

WaniKani also suggests it might mean *motor-mouth*, as in someone who talks and talks and won't shut up.

Comment: 早　is the kanji from 早い

Answer (score 14, accepted):

早口 is a noun or no-/na-adjective that just means "talking rapidly". To use it adverbially, 早口に喋る and 早口で喋る are both okay. Among the three bullets you gave, 早口 covers only the first one. It doesn't mean someone won't shut up, either.

To describe a fast-talking salesman, [よく口が回る](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E8%89%AF%E3%81%8F%E5%8F%A3%E3%81%AE%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8B) is a set phrase that has a mild negative connotation. 舌が回る is equally common and negative.